# The compiler gives me a warning on a HTML table

Tags: html

The compiler gives me the following warning

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- NLS missing message: 
 Obsolete_attribute_name___ERROR_ in: 
 org.eclipse.wst.html.core.internal.HTMLCorePluginResources
```

Here is my code:

```
 <table width="525" height="177" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="69" height="30">姓名：</td>
        <td width="166">${sessionScope.userInfo.realname}</td>
        <td width="59">性别：</td>
        <td width="154">${sessionScope.userInfo.sex}</td>
        <td width="121" rowspan="4" valign="top"><img src="${sessionScope.userInfo.headgif}"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="30">邮箱：</td>
        <td>${sessionScope.userInfo.email}</td>
        <td>电话：</td>
        <td>${sessionScope.userInfo.tel}</td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
        <td height="30">职业：</td>
        <td>${sessionScope.userInfo.profession}</td>
        <td>QQ号码：</td>
        <td>${sessionScope.userInfo.qq}</td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
        <td height="30">家庭住址：</td>
        <td colspan="3">${sessionScope.userInfo.address}</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
        <td height="30">主页：</td>
        <td colspan="4">${sessionScope.userInfo.homepage}</td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
        <td height="30">个人描述：</td>
        <td colspan="4">${sessionScope.userInfo.self}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>




    </td>
    <td width="180" align="center" valign="top" background="images/b_r_2.gif"><jsp:include page="blog_right.jsp" flush="true"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please specify which compiler you are using, and add suitable tags; this is surely not a pure HTML question.

Answer (score 2):

> Obsolete_attribute_name

Every attribute you have on your `<table>` element has a CSS equivalent (introduced in the late 1990s) that you should use instead.

`width`,  `height`,  `border`, `margin`, `padding` (on the TD elements) and `border-collapse` respectively.

---

As an aside:

```
</table>
<br>
</td>
```

- `<br>` elements should not be used to simulate `padding`
- Tables should almost never be nested. Nested tables are a strong sign of layout tables, which [should not be used](http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/).

Comment: The "should not be used" link is just a list of unsubstantiated claims and bad navigation.  Do you have any other resources?

Comment: "Tables should not be used purely as a means to layout document content" — http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html

Answer (score 0):

Is it bad formatting or bad code sample?
You have open `<br>` tag but no closing `</br>` tag before second closing `</table>` tag.

```
</td>
<td width="180" align="center" valign="top" background="images/b_r_2.gif"><jsp:include page="blog_right.jsp" flush="true"/></td>
```

Comment: `<br>` is defined as an empty element. It can't have an end tag (except in XHTML, which is not listed in the tags on the question).

Comment: Thanks that's new to me, I just used it as self closing tab. And couldn't use it within the table tags. I thought it a bit strange having two closing `</table>` tags with one `<table>` opening tag and `<br>` tag inside.

Comment: Presumably there is another table start tag in the code before the code that was copied into the question

Comment: hi,here is my another question.How can i post only text in the stackoverflow.i have done that just now but it says i don't meet the format